# Http failure during parsing for get Request, which responses csv formatted data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, csv, parse-error

i have some issues with handling an http get request, which delivers CSV formatted data.
This data can not be parsed into JSON, so the error message "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/auth/realms/..." occurs.
So my question is: how can i parse those data into JSON?

[Here is the Payload from the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cc9R.png)

Comment: You'll have to fetch it as text and then process it yourself using some custom code, unless you can find a library which already has an algorithm for creating a basic JSON array from such a dataset.